# Nested grid extending to the end of the view

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

As shown in the screenshot below, I'm trying to achieve "Lg" by using Grid (from [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/))

- The box with number "3" is created by using a grid of `9` and `3`
- The box with number "9" is created by using a grid of `9` and `9`

**Question**:
How can I get the width of `Lg` by using the Grid system? Basically `Sm` and `Lg` are calculated using:

- Sm: 100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3
- Lg: 100% - 100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3

**Example code**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { Grid, Box } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "bisque",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  boxSm: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "calc(100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3)",
  },
  boxLg: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "calc(100% - 100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3)",
  },
  box: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function AutoGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid container xs={9} spacing={0}>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>3</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={9}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>9</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Box className={classes.container}>
        <Box className={classes.boxSm}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>Sm</Paper>
        </Box>
        <Box className={classes.boxLg}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>Lg</Paper>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box className={classes.box}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>Full width</Paper>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well If you define your xs and lg screens it will work automatically when you switch from small to large screens.

```
<Grid container xs={9} lg={12} spacing={0}>
      <Grid item lg={6} xs={3}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>3</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={6} xs={9}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>9</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

So here you can define what will be the size on specific screen as soon as you switch to large screen it will extend to the end of the view.  Full code

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { Grid, Box } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
flexGrow: 1,
backgroundColor: "bisque",
padding: theme.spacing(1),
},
paper: {
 padding: theme.spacing(2),
 textAlign: 'center',
 color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
},
container: {
display: "flex",
},
boxSm: {
marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
width: "calc(100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3)",
},
boxLg: {
marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
width: "calc(100% - 100% / 12 * 9 / 12 * 3)",
},
box: {
marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
},
}));

export default function App() {
const classes = useStyles();

return (
 <div className={classes.root}>
  <Grid container>
    <Grid container xs={9} lg={12} spacing={0}>
      <Grid item lg={6} xs={3}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>3</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={6} xs={9}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>9</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
   <Box className={classes.container}>
    <Box className={classes.boxSm}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Sm</Paper>
    </Box>
    <Box className={classes.boxLg}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Lg</Paper>
    </Box>
  </Box>
  <Box className={classes.box}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>Full width</Paper>
  </Box>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work. The box with "9" still doesn't extend to the end of the view.